# Automatically Populated Empty Value In ng-model ,data getting from ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Have List of Object I am Iterating using `ng-options` inside `select` tag

For that list of object has empty value below I posted my sample data I highlighted that empty data also I posted my code .

JSON DATA:

```
$scope.dummyData =    [
        {
            "id": "0a40f753-0919-4bb2-b64e-74a280695ac6",
            "buildName": "JackPot",
            "department": "",
            "floor": "",
            "roomno": "12345Room",
            "wing": "TEST"
        },
        {
            "id": "1ff0d1e3-c347-41ce-8b96-acb695bba7a8",
            "buildName": "JackPot",
            "department": "Dept",
            "floor": "Testing",
            "roomno": "123f",
            "wing": "Test"
        }
    ]
```

above JSON data has **floor:""** empty value .

Code:

```
<select ng-model="buildNameng" ng-options="option.floor as option.floor for option in dummyData | unique:'buildName'" style="width:12%" ng-change="buildCh(buildNameng)">
  <!-- You can have ONE default, null selection option.--
          <option value="">---Building---</option>
              </select>
```

If the `$scope.dummyData` Json floor has empty the  dropdown automatically changed in to empty value. The problem here is if I am getting an Empty value Inside floor like above JSON .The `ng-model="buildNameng"` automatically populated that empty value even if that has one more not null value . The ng-model `buildNameng`automatically Populated into empty data first . I dont Know How to control this ?

I know another way the above select tag in no-options change like this I got the output but purposefully I dont want like this .

```
 ng-options="option.id as option.floor for option in dummyData | unique:'buildName'"
```

I need to control that empty data automatically populated in program thats the problem also. Please guide me I am searching a lot but I couldn't find

Comment: What does this have anything to do with backbone.js or node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the chosenCat array with a for loop and remove every array item that does not have a defined floor before displaying the data.

```
var dummyData =    [
        {
            "id": "0a40f753-0919-4bb2-b64e-74a280695ac6",
            "buildName": "JackPot",
            "department": "",
            "floor": "",
            "roomno": "12345Room",
            "wing": "TEST"
        },
        {
            "id": "1ff0d1e3-c347-41ce-8b96-acb695bba7a8",
            "buildName": "JackPot",
            "department": "Dept",
            "floor": "Testing",
            "roomno": "123f",
            "wing": "Test"
        }
    ];

for(var i = 0; i < dummyData.length; i++) {
    if (!dummyData[i].floor); {
    dummyData.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
$scope.dummyData = dummyData;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using [**`angular-filter`**](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter),  so you can simple use the [**`angular-filter#removewith`**](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#removewith) `filter`, as below:

```
removeWith: { floor: '' }
```

Take a look on this simple example:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app', ['angular.filter'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);

  function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.dummyData = [  
       {  
          "id":"0a40f753-0919-4bb2-b64e-74a280695ac6",
          "buildName":"JackPot",
          "department":"",
          "floor":"",
          "roomno":"12345Room",
          "wing":"TEST"
       },
       {  
          "id":"1ff0d1e3-c347-41ce-8b96-acb695bba7a8",
          "buildName":"JackPot2",
          "department":"Dept",
          "floor":"Testing",
          "roomno":"123f",
          "wing":"Test"
       }
    ];
  } 
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.9/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="buildNameng" ng-options="option.floor as option.floor for option in dummyData | unique: 'buildName' | removeWith: { floor: '' }">
    <option value="">---Building---</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: yes , it works fine but I need to show that empty value in that drop down thats what I want . Because I have a requirement if the drop down has empty value with other values user may choose it which one he wants .

Comment: Só what's the question?

Comment: I changed my ng-options like `ng-options="option.id as option.floor for option in dummyData | unique:'buildName'"` this it works fine but in my `ngmodel` i dont want get that id . I want to get floor value , so my problem here is if that array list has empty value with other value(not null) . the `ngmodel` automatically populated first that empty value in that drop down thats is the problem I am facing

Comment: But when you use this construction the empty floor appears?

Comment: s it appears , i have another condition if that floor array list doesnt has value automatically that empty data shown user didnt touch that drop down .

Comment: if i am using ng-options `ng-options="option.floor as option.floor for option in dummyData` like this the empty value automatically populated

Comment: Try it: `ng-options="option.floor for option in dummyData | unique:'buildName' track by option.id"`

Comment: But if the array list has a value with null values  . I want to user select that drop down but angular automatically shown first empty value in that  drop down value thats the problem

Comment: Did it change anything?

Comment: actually I need to check some other condition using the code what u gave that ng-options dude sure I wil let u know

Comment: Above json I tested bro , it shown the empty data only in that drop down I am not getting the `floor:testing` value in that same drop down , but **I am not getting automatically populated in that ngmodel null value **